# JAXB exception messages: How to change language?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, internationalization, jaxb2

During XML validation against an XSD file using JAXB I get `JAXBExceptions` in case of invalid XML files. I get the message of the exceptions by calling `event.getMessage()`. The resulting string is in german language.

I'm using JAXB 2.2. with java 8 on a german system.

**What determines the language for the JAXB exception messages and how can I change it to english?**

Here's the code:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
try {
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("myPackage");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new XMLValidationEventHandler());
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    myClass = (myClass) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("myFile.xml"));

} catch (SAXException saxE) {
    System.out.println("SAX-Exception during creation of Schema object!");
    saxE.printStackTrace();
} catch (JAXBException e) {}
```

And this is the Event-Handler:

```
public class XMLValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

@Override
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
    System.out.println("XML validation failure in line " 
                       + event.getLocator().getLineNumber() 
                       + ", column " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber() 
                       + ": " + event.getMessage());
    return true;
}
```

Here is an example of the output of the event handler:

```
XML validation failure in line 8, column 48: cvc-maxInclusive-valid: Wert "10000" ist nicht Facet-gültig in Bezug auf maxInclusive "8.0E3" für Typ "Type".
XML validation failure in line 17, column 64: Ungültiger Wert 250 für Feld Day.
XML validation failure in line 17, column 64: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: "2014-02-2501:00:00Z" ist kein gültiger Wert für "dateTime".
```

Comment: Please post the code sample used to get the message, and the exact output if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found out that the language used for the JAXB event messages is determined by the java system property `user.language`. The default language is therefore dependent on the system it runs on.

I changed the run configuration of my java program by adding `-Duser.language=en`. This changed the language of the JAXB event messages to english.

Comment: Is there a way to to set the Locale just for the current JAXB context, without changing the default Locale for the whole JVM? 

I tried setting property "http://apache.org/xml/properties/locale" when creating the JAXBContext, but that throws an exception. It is not propagated to the underlying SaxParser.

Comment: @fuemf5, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a validator to validate, not unmarshaller. You can change its locale like this:

```
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
ErrorHandler errorHandler = new YourErrorHandler();
validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

XMLErrorReporter xmlErrorReporter = (XMLErrorReporter) validator
        .getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/error-reporter");
xmlErrorReporter.setLocale(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
```

Though with Java9+ you'd need to export the `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl` package from the `java.xml` module via compiler option. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42541096/1341535) for more details.