# Error while creating EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm making a Java application using JavaFX and Hibernate and when creating EntityManagerFactory this error pops out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Transport] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1495)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1415)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at org.application/org.application.App.<clinit>(App.java:19)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1410)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:612)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:155)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:53)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class org.application.Przystanki$HibernateProxy$sCX2Dgdo (in module org.application) cannot access class org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration (in unnamed module @0x56e9a474) because module org.application does not read unnamed module @0x56e9a474
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:1624)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$AbstractBase.inject(ClassInjector.java:114)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$UsingLookup.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:492)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:100)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:6154)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:182)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:153)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class org.application.Przystanki$HibernateProxy$sCX2Dgdo (in module org.application) cannot access class org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration (in unnamed module @0x56e9a474) because module org.application does not read unnamed module @0x56e9a474
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2127)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:962)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingLookup.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:1622)
    ... 48 more
```

I believe it showed up after an IDE update.

None of this happens when all the classes run wild and free without any packages and modules but thats what JavaFX needs so there they are.

I've spent a day or so searching for answers or clues but I have no idea how to fix it. I am a total newbie in all of this and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can see a similar kind of issue at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647605/2933389. Can you please look at this answer, if it can help.

Comment: @ParameshKorrakuti I see how my error looks similar to that in the link, but I don't know how to relate to it nor how to apply that soluthion to my situation. I do export my module `org.application`. Feel free to say where my thinking is wrong

Comment: Hope, this answer help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42541096/2933389.

Comment: So tell me if I'm thinking correctly - I need to export my module to `ALL-UNNAMED` at a compilation level using a --add-exports command?

Comment: Try making your module open and export all packages i.e. `open module org.application { exports org.application; }`

Answer (score 2):

From stack trace, I assuming that you are using Java modules and your error is probably related with incorrect modules configuration in your `package-info.java` file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superinterface check failed: class org.application.Przystanki$HibernateProxy$sCX2Dgdo (in module org.application) cannot access class org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration (in unnamed module @0x56e9a474) because module org.application does not read unnamed module @0x56e9a474
```

In module `org.application`, please add in `module-info.java`:

```
requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
```